# How many static IP's do I need for VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

I am setting up a VPN system for my office. Is it correct that if I don't have a dedicated VPN server, I will need to purchase one static IP per computer I wish to connect to? Or can I just give the router a static IP, and then configure the router to give each computer it connects to a dedicated IP?

We just have a couple of people so I am okay manually configuring static IP's for each of the computers.

Comment: One static IP.  But you haven't said much about what you want.  I suggest you get someone who knows what they are doing to set this up for you rather than fumble it through yourself.  It sounds like you're not a sysadmin.

Comment: How much research have you done in learning how VPNs work?  I'll admit that I haven't done a lot of research into VPNs, but as I understand it, the VPN is just a bridge between multiple networks so that the multiple networks act like one network (in spite of the gulf that is the internet between them).  (In this context, one machine can act as a network in isolation, and it doesn't care about sharing the local network with the other network)

Comment: Question is confusing, you are mixing some technology or architecture concepts. You don't "need" static IPs if you use dynamic DNS, and a DHCP pool for the clients...but, in a typical setup, the VPN server/end-point would be the only thing that would be on a static.

Comment: @jlehtinen thanks, I think my question is "do I have to purchase a server solely for the purpose of VPN or can I just buy one static IP for each computer and use each one as a mini server?"

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: @Xodarap It appears that even you don't quite know what you're asking.  I personally recommend closing this question, doing a good quantity of research into the subject, so that you know a lot more, and then later come back with a better question (if you still have any).  But, that's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one static wan ip for the dedicated firewall/vpn server which will generally give you a dhcp lease on another network and it will handle the nat between the vpn network and the internal lan.

Comment: I call foul.  I think the answer was pre-emptively accepted to make the asking person seem to have asked something less foolish, ambiguous, or vague than was actually asked.